# std::is_invocable syntax for testing existence of an arbitrary method (not only operator())

Tags: c++, c++17, metaprogramming, type-traits

In C++17 I know that I can write:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
  size_t operator()(double x) const { return 1; };
};

int main()
{
  static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<size_t, A, double>);  
}
```

However now I want to use [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) to test the existence of an arbitrary method (here the `size(double)` method):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
  size_t size(double x) const { return 1; };
};

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<size_t, ???, double>);  
}
```

The question is **how one must fill the "???" to make it works** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [detection idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected):

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
using call_size_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().size(std::declval<Args>()...);

template <typename R, typename T, typename... Args>
using is_size_callable = is_detected_convertible<R, call_size_t, T, Args...>;

static_assert(is_size_callable<size_t, A, double>::value);
```

This has the benefit of working with member functions `size` that are overloaded, templates, or take default arguments as well.

---

In C++20 with concepts:

```
template <typename T, typename R, typename... Args>
concept is_size_callable = requires (T t, Args... args) {
    { t.size(std::forward<Args>(args)...) } -> std::convertible_to<R>;
};

static_assert(is_size_callable<A, size_t, double>);
```

I flipped the arguments to put `T` first, since this would allow the *type-constraint* syntax:

```
template <is_size_callable<size_t, double> T>
void foo(T );

foo(A{});
```

Comment: Thanks for this longer, but more general solution!

Comment: Value cats are the best cats :)

Comment: @T.C. Nevertheless I was happy with my solution :-)

Comment: @T.C. Uh, value dogs, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

[c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
#define RETURNS( ... ) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define METHOD( ... )  \
    []( auto&& self, auto&&...args ) \
    RETURNS( decltype(self)(self).__VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )

struct A
{
  std::size_t size(double x) const { return 1; };
};

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_r<std::size_t, decltype(METHOD(size)), A&, double>{});  
}
```

and [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
#define RETURNS( ... ) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }

#define METHOD( ... )  \
    []( auto&& self, auto&&...args ) \
    RETURNS( decltype(self)(self).__VA_ARGS__( decltype(args)(args)... ) )

auto call_size = METHOD(size);
struct A
{
  std::size_t size(double x) const { return 1; };
};

int main()
{
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_r<std::size_t, decltype(call_size), A&, double>{});  
}
```

(note: I use `...` because macros don't know of `<,>` style brackets and commas)

Comment: Thank you, it is a cheaper solution that works and that does not require std::experimental (detection_idiom)

Comment: What's the difference between both versions?

Comment: @0x499602D2 lambda in unevaluated context.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the right syntax is:

```
static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<size_t, decltype(&A::size), A, double>);
```

Here is a working example

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ -std=c++17 demo.cpp -o demo"; -*-

#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
  size_t operator()(double x) const { return 1; };
  size_t size(double x) const { return 1; };
};

int main()
{
  static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<size_t, A, double>);  

  static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<size_t, decltype(&A::size), A, double>); 

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```