# C++20 std::invocable syntax

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to write this

```
    template <typename F, typename... Args> requires std::invocable<F&, Args...>
    void applyFunction(F&& f, Args&&... args) {

    }
```

without `requires` clause, so I want something like

```
template <std::invocable<F, Args...>>
    void applyFunction(F&& f, Args&&... args) {

    }
```

...but it fails to compile. I searched StackOverflow but couldn't find how to use the correct syntax.
How can I use terse syntax correctly?

**UPDATE**: I found that this works:

```
    template <typename... Args, std::invocable<Args...> F>
    void applyFunction(F&& f, Args&&... args) {

    }
```

Still ugly. Any better way?

Comment: What is the error? What if you search for the error online?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt https://stackoverflow.com/a/59160506/7772722 This was the closest I could find, but this syntax only allows to use with fixed number of function arguments, not variadic number of arguments.

Comment: "*without requires clause*" Why is that so important? It's OK to use `requires` clauses.

Comment: Yes, it works without problem, but then one could say "Who need ```concept```s? What's wrong with ```std::enable_if_t``` equilibristics? It works well anyway".. I want to write a cleaner, shorter, more concise code.

Comment: @frozenca: "*then one could say "What's wrong with std::enable_if_t equilibristics? It works well anyway"*" Any "one" who said that would be wrong, as there are several significant problems with using `enable_if` gymnastics. Concepts weren't invented just because `enable_if` was wordy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a concept in place of `typename` in a template parameter list only works when you are replacing one of the concept's template parameters. Specifically, the first one.

If you have two (or more) template parameters that share a relationship, odds are good that you will need to have a `requires` clause. And you need to make your peace with that. Indeed, putting the parameter pack in front of the function as you have done in the template argument list has consequences. It pretty much impossible for a user to specify the callable type parameter directly when calling the function, and thus the user would be forced to rely on template argument deduction.

Don't try to force syntax to work just because it takes a couple fewer keystrokes to type. Write in the way that makes the most sense for what you're doing, that makes it the most clear as to what is going on.